# What is new in Akavache v6.0.17-beta that i can tap(I cant find the release note)

Tags: akavache

What is new in Akavache v6.0.17-beta that i can tap(I cant find the release note)

I am have been waiting for any update on this great library.

Comment: Added the release notes, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the release notes:

https://github.com/reactiveui/Akavache/releases/tag/6.0.17-beta

Just updated them with all the updates in the version.